How do I efficiently read text files with complex multi-line data in Python?
In my search for a suitable solution, I came across various approaches such as numpy.loadtxt or numpy.genfromtxt that seemed promising at first glance, but didn't work straight-forwardly.
The Challenges
One line of my dataset is multiline, see the first two rows:
[array([[ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  0, -1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
       [-2, -1,  0, -1, -1],
       [-2, -2,  0, -1,  0]]), 24, 4, 0, 232, 988, 1464, 10, 8, 246, 12]
[array([[ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [-1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  0],
       [-1, -1,  0,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
       [ 0, -2, -2, -2, -1]]), 28, 4, 0, 244, 1036, 1536, 10, 8, 260, 13]
...

CAS (computer algebra system) generate this output and my influence on the output format is limited.
The file is not very small, it can grow (after collecting more data) up to 3 GB.
What I tried so far
Trying to read data using np.genfromtxt('polytopes_5d_reflexive.txt') does not work seamlessly. Classic line-by-line reading is also not advantageous, as the number of lines describing one data row varies.
The Background
The saying goes "mathematical data is inexpensive". In our case, we actually generate such data ourselves, namely five-dimensional polytopes, in order to examine their properties such as vertex number, volume and others.
I do not want to demand a ready-made solution, but I am very grateful for the thought-inducing impulse in the right direction.

You should be writing your datafiles in a more user-friendly format, e.g. JSON. Then they would be easy to read back in.

You are totally right. I have unfortunatelly not so much influence on the format, since members from math team use algebraic tools that are strong in mathematical terms but not so strong in terms of "fancy" outputs. They yield the data as given in my post.

That is unfortunate. So is the above the exact text format of the file?

Yes - it is the exact output. I have presented a real data excerpt above.

One possible solution is to use re/ast.literal_eval to parse the file. But yes, more correct solution would be to use proper serialization format (such as Json...):
import re
from ast import literal_eval

import numpy as np

txt = """\
[array([[ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  0, -1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
       [-2, -1,  0, -1, -1],
       [-2, -2,  0, -1,  0]]), 24, 4, 0, 232, 988, 1464, 10, 8, 246, 12]
[array([[ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [-1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  0],
       [-1, -1,  0,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
       [ 0, -2, -2, -2, -1]]), 28, 4, 0, 244, 1036, 1536, 10, 8, 260, 13]"""


for line in re.findall(r"^\[.*?\]$", txt, flags=re.S | re.M):
    arr, *rest = literal_eval(line.replace("array", ""))
    print(np.array(arr))
    print(rest)
    print()

Prints:
[[ 1  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  1  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  1  0  0]
 [ 1  0 -1  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  1  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  1]
 [-2 -1  0 -1 -1]
 [-2 -2  0 -1  0]]
[24, 4, 0, 232, 988, 1464, 10, 8, 246, 12]

[[ 1  0  0  0  0]
 [-1  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  1  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  1  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  1  0]
 [-1 -1  0  1  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  1]
 [ 0 -2 -2 -2 -1]]
[28, 4, 0, 244, 1036, 1536, 10, 8, 260, 13]

